# Select different column value from different row for a same id in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Table name - Product

| ID | product_id | product_value10 | product_value20 | product_value30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | **101** | 111 | 111 |
| 1 | 20 | 222 | **201** | 222 |
| 1 | 30 | 333 | 333 | **301** |
| 2 | 10 | **102** | 111 | 222 |
| 2 | 20 | 888 | **202** | 333 |
| 2 | 30 | 888 | 555 | **302** |
| 3 | 10 | **103** | 999 | 111 |
| 3 | 20 | 666 | **203** | 888 |
| 3 | 30 | 999 | 999 | **303** |

I want a output as below

| ID | Product_value10 | Product_value20 | Product_value30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 201 | 301 |
| 2 | 102 | 202 | 302 |
| 3 | 103 | 203 | 303 |

Comment: Please, [**do not post images of data**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). Especially some text of the question inside it. You may just copy that same output and paste it here as text.

Comment: Please, describe how to identify values in bold. Can they be calculated for each ID or are they present in some other table?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
  SELECT id,
         SUM (product_value1) AS product_value1,
         SUM (product_value2) AS product_value2,
         SUM (product_value3) AS product_value3
    FROM product
GROUP BY id
```